# Multivariable limits: $ \lim_{{(x,y) \to (0,0)}} \frac{{x^4 + y^4}}{{\sqrt{{x^2 + y^4}}}} $

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

> $$ \text{Evaluate the following limit: }
> A= \lim_{{(x,y) \to (0,0)}} \frac{{x^4 + y^4}}{{\sqrt{{x^2 + y^4}}}}$$

I've tried using polar coordinates, but am having trouble solving this.

$$
\lim_{{r \to 0}} \frac{{(r\cos(\theta))^4 + (r\sin(\theta))^4}}{{\sqrt{{(r\cos(\theta))^2 + (r\sin(\theta))^4}}}}
$$

After substituting, my first thought was to rationalize the denominator, which resulted in this:

$$
\lim_{{r \to 0}} \frac{{\sqrt{{(r\cos(\theta))^2 + (r\sin(\theta))^4)}}{{(r\cos(\theta))^4 + (r\sin(\theta))^4)
}}}}{{(r\cos(\theta))^2 + (r\sin(\theta))^4}}
$$

But from here I'm having trouble moving forward.

Can anyone provide any hints or tips? Would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: $x^4\leq(x^2+y^4)^2$ and $y^4\leq x^2+y^4$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\lim_{{(x,y) \to (0,0)}} \frac{{x^4 + y^4}}{{\sqrt{{x^2 + y^4}}}}$$
Note that :
$$0\le\left|  \frac{{x^4 + y^4}}{{\sqrt{{x^2 + y^4}}}}\right| \le \left|  \frac{{x^4 }}{{\sqrt{{x^2+y^4}}}}\right|+\left|  \frac{{y^4 }}{{\sqrt{{x^2 + y^4}}}}\right|\le\left|  \frac{{x^4 }}{{\sqrt{{x^2}}}}\right|+\left|  \frac{{y^4 }}{{\sqrt{{ y^4}}}}\right|=|x^3|+y^2$$
and the last term approaches $0$ as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$. You conclude applying the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Using mean inequality to scale numerators and denominators separately
$$x^4+y^4\leq 2\sqrt{x^4 y^4}=2x^2 y^2$$
$$x^2+y^4\ge 2\lvert x \rvert y^2$$
So $$\frac{x^4+y^4}{\sqrt{x^2+y^4}}\leq\sqrt{2}(\lvert x \rvert)^{\frac{3}{2}}\lvert y \rvert$$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You could factor and then divide $r^2$:

$$
\begin{align}{\lim\limits_{{r \to 0}} \dfrac{{\sqrt{{(r\cos(\theta))^2 + (r\sin(\theta))^4}}{{(r\cos(\theta))^4 + (r\sin(\theta))^4)
}}}}{{(r\cos(\theta))^2 + (r\sin(\theta))^4}}} 
\ \quad
=\lim\limits_{{r \to 0}} \dfrac{r^5\cdot{\sqrt{{\cos^2{\theta} + r^2\sin^4{\theta}}}{{ \space\cdot \left(\cos^4{\theta} + \sin^4{\theta}\right)
}}}}{{r^2 \cdot\left(1 - \sin^2(\theta) + r^2\sin^4{\theta}\right)}}\end{align}
$$

$$=\lim\limits_{{r \to 0}} \dfrac{r^3\cdot{\sqrt{{\cos^2{\theta} + r^2\sin^4{\theta}}}{{ \space\cdot \left(\cos^4{\theta} + \sin^4{\theta}\right)
}}}}{{\left(1 - \sin^2(\theta) + r^2\sin^4{\theta}\right)}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

We don't have to directly employ polar coordinates for this problem. Instead, we can adapt the concept and tailor it specifically to better tuned to the structure of OP's problem.

To do this, we make the following substitutions:

$$ \rho = \sqrt{x^2 + y^4}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\lambda = (x/\rho)^2.$$

With these, we see that $0 \leq \lambda \leq 1$ and $\rho \to 0$ as $(x,y)\to (0, 0)$. Furthermore, by using the relationships $ x^2 = \lambda \rho^2 $ and $ y^4 = (1-\lambda)\rho^2 $, we get

$$ \frac{x^4 + y^4}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^4}} = \frac{\rho^4\lambda^2 + (1-\lambda)\rho^2}{\rho} = \rho \left[ \rho^2\lambda^2 + (1-\lambda) \right]. $$

The last expression is bounded by $\rho(\rho^2 + 1)$, which tends to $0$ as $(x, y) \to 0$. Therefore we conclude that the limit converges to $0$ by the squeezing theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Just observe that

$$0\leq\frac{x^4+y^4}{\sqrt{x^2+y^4}}=\frac{(x^2)^2+y^4}{\sqrt{x^2+y^4}}\leq\frac{(x^2+y^4)^2+x^2+y^4}{\sqrt{x^2+y^4}}=(x^2+y^4)^{3/2}+\sqrt{x^2+y^4}\to0$$

as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$.